# linux + file output manipulation

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

we have the follwing file ( could be the same line more or less )

```
more /tmp/info

linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex: Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex: Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex: Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Link detected: yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Link detected: yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Link detected: yes
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
```

how to manipulate the output so we get the follwing

expected results  ( with lines indention )

```
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Speed     10000Mb/s


linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex        Full



linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Link_detected  yes
```

Comment: you need indention or add empty lines between? or both? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: yes we need to indent the lines

Comment: @jango, then you should describe the indentation logic: how should the 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th block be indented and you should specify the indentation size

Comment: yes only 4th as linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Speed   10000Mb/s ( we can ignore : "

Comment: see my update in the question

Comment: what does mean your "*yes only 4th*"? you don't have any 4th. Be more exact

Comment: I mean 4 fields

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two outputs you are trying to achieve? Aligned colons?

Comment: @jango, you did not describe your indentation logic - for now, it looks arbitrary

Comment: less or more according my expected results see the update

Comment: @jango, what is the problem with describing the indentation logic? why should the 3rd block not be indented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'prev && prev != $3 { print ORS ORS }{ prev = $3 }1' /tmp/info
```

The output:

```
linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Speed: 10000Mb/s



linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex: Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex: Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Duplex: Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Duplex: Full



linux01.sys76.com eno83122  Link detected: yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122  Link detected: yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122  Link detected: yes
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux01.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux02.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
linux03.sys76.com eno83122 Link detected: yes
```

Comment: is it include lines indentation  ?

Comment: see my update in the question